# Move first instance of each cell value from one to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move the first instances of each value of the column "firstname" from one sheet to another. I am able to move the first instance of the first cell value from the firstname column, but I am not able to move the next and so on till the end. Below is the code I am working with at the moment.

Is there any problem with the for loops?

```
Option Explicit
Private Const RAW_DATA_SHEET = "UserDetails" 

Private Const REPORT_SHEET = "Report"

Private Const USER_NAME_COL = "User Name"
Private Const FIRST_NAME_COL = "First Name"
Private Const LAST_NAME_COL = "Last Name"


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()



Dim firstname As String
Dim firstnameActive As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim sheetre As Worksheet
Dim userNameHeader As Range
Dim firstnameHeader As Range
Dim userToFindRow As Range
Dim user As String
Dim curcell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set sheetre = Sheets("Report")
Set sheet = Sheets("UserDetails")
For Each firstnameHeader In sheet.Range("B2" & sheet.Range("B" &    sheet.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)

Set curcell = sheetre.Range("A3")
' Find the columns of "User Name"
Set userNameHeader = sheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=USER_NAME_COL, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'note: SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

Set firstnameHeader = sheet.Rows(1).Find(What:=FIRST_NAME_COL, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'note: SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

' Use to find the row number of the provided user
Set userToFindRow = sheet.Columns(userNameHeader.Column).Find(What:=user, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'note: SearchOrder:=xlByRows


For Each userToFindRow In sheet.Range("E2" & sheet.Range("E" &  sheet.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
' Get the value of "firstname" cell for provided user
Set firstnameActive = sheet.Cells(userToFindRow.Column, firstnameHeader.Column)


If Not IsEmpty(firstnameActive) Then

curcell.Value = firstnameActive
Set curcell = curcell.Offset(1)
End If
Next userToFindRow
Next firstnameHeader


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

why the loop is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sathak, I think you need to change your For Each Loop. Syntax of For each is we tend to search in defined range. You need to add **:B** & **:E** in both for each range to make loop work.

Check the modified code and try to use this For Each loop in your code:

First For each loop:

```
For Each firstnameHeader In sheet.Range("B2:B" & sheet.Range("B" & sheet.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Second For each loop:

```
For Each userToFindRow In sheet.Range("E2:E" & sheet.Range("E" & sheet.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But still i can move only the first instance of the first value, except that this time after changing the code the value is moved to the all the cells of the row (equal to number of rows in another sheet) to which i want to move and not just one cell in that row. Where do you reckon the issue is? Can you help me out?